# Send Data Across NICs Using socat

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, wireshark, socat

I'm working on a project trying to develop a data diode for unidirectional transfer of data, and I'm hoping to use socat for some measurements. As a first step, I want to use socat to send data from one NIC across an ethernet cable to another NIC on the same PC. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I manually configured IP addresses for each NIC, then connected them together using an ethernet cable. Finally, I added a manual arp entry:

```
$ sudo arp -s 10.0.1.1 48:21:0b:3e:76:ce -i enp89s0
$ arp -a
story-NUC11 (10.0.1.1) at 48:21:0b:3e:76:ce [ether] PERM on enp89s0
...
```

Details about each NIC:

```
NIC 1: enp88s0
inet 10.0.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
ether 48:21:0b:3e:76:ce

NIC 2: enp89s0
inet 10.0.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
ether 48:21:0b:3e:4f:df
```

I thought that transferring data from NIC 2 to NIC 1 would be as simple as running these socat commands:

```
# To receive on NIC 1
socat -u UDP-RECV:1234,bind=10.0.1.1,so-bindtodevice=enp88s0 -

# To send to NIC 1 using NIC 2
socat -u - UDP:10.0.1.1:1234,so-bindtodevice=enp89s0
```

However, no such luck. The receive command never echos any output.

When I listen to enp88s0 (NIC 1) using Wireshark (edit: and tcpdump), I see the UDP packets that NIC 2 is sending. I also observed the loopback interface using tcpdump, and I didn't see any packets transfer over loopback. Since the data is going across the ethernet cable, this suggests that my receive command isn't correct. However, I've tried many permutations, and my receive command never echoes anything. Any ideas?

Edit: Switched IPs to 10.0.1.X subnet.

Comment: This might be a red herring, but you probably shouldn't be using the IPv4 link-local subnet for this, as it has special rules that might be getting in your way. Use an RFC 1918 private subnet and put both NICs on the same subnet. By the way, forcing a modern network stack to actually send data across the wire between two local NICs usually isn't this easy. Stacks usually recognize that the traffic is meant for itself and loop it back internally. I'm not sure if socat's bind directive is enough to overcome this, and I'm not sure if you can trust what the network stack is telling Wireshark.

Comment: Good idea: I switched to the 10.0.1.X subnet. Unfortunately, I still don't see any output. I also monitored the packets using tcpdump, and I counted the change in packets TX and RX in ifconfig – everything seems to confirm that the data is being sent to the interface, but the socat receive command isn't printing it.

Answer (score 0):

The command looks well; when doing tcpdump/wireshark on enp88s0 you might check the MAC addresses, just to be sure the packet uses the wire.

Try the receiver without the bind (thus only with so-bindtodevice), and vice versa!

Comment: Unfortunately, varying the binds on the receiver gave me the same results. I did find a solution using network namespaces, which I will share below.

This is what I see in tcpdump:
11:32:07.166085 48:21:0b:3e:4f:df > 48:21:0b:3e:76:ce, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 60: 10.0.1.2.42316 > 10.0.1.1.1234: UDP, length 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why socat wasn't working in this situation, but I did find a solution using network namespaces, based on [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/861465).

For my unidirectional use-case:

```
# Create a sender namespace
sudo ip netns add sender

# Move link into sender namespace
sudo ip link set enp89s0 netns sender

# Set the ip for the link
sudo ip netns exec sender ip addr add dev enp89s0 10.0.1.2/24

# Bring the link up
sudo ip netns exec sender ip link set dev enp89s0 up

# Where should outbound traffic go? To 10.0.1.1.
# Destination IPs must be on the same subnet as this interface's IP. 
sudo ip netns exec sender route add default gw 10.0.1.1

# Add manual ARP entry
sudo ip netns exec sender arp -s 10.0.1.1 48:21:0b:3e:76:ce -i enp89s0
```

Then, I simply run the sender in the network namespace, and the receiver has no trouble receiving the data:

```
sudo ip netns exec sender socat -u - UDP:10.0.1.1:1234,so-bindtodevice=enp89s0
```

In fact, none of the explicit binding to interfaces is even necessary when using namespaces. So it suffices to use the commands:

```
# Receiver
socat -u UDP-RECV:1234 -

# Sender
sudo ip netns exec sender socat -u - UDP:10.0.1.1:1234
```

Network namespaces are the way to go!